# Android setVisibility(View.GONE) Error Cannot resolve symbol 'GONE'

Tags: android, webview, view

I got error must be one of:View.ViSIBLE, View.GONE... anyone know why View.GONE is giving error of: Cannot resolve symbol 'GONE'...and View.Visible also.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView mWebView;
    Object View;
    Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ww);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new runbutton());

    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showShare(){
            bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void hideShare(){
            bt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you miss the import for View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you need `Object View;` in variables?

Remove it and add this statement in import part.

```
import android.view.View;
```

Comment: But the button is not showing..am i missed something in code?

Comment: One point you missed @JavascriptInterface annotation in ```hideShare``` methods. If not, you may need to check the code of web. Android code does not seem to be a problem.